# Second level cache config

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

I have Hibernate ehcache 4.1.4 final, ehcache-3.3.0.jar

config(spring 3.2) for hibernate ehcache

```
 hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true    
            hibernate.generate_statistics=true         
            hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
```

My entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SESSION_ENTERING")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class SESSION_ENTERING implements Serializable {
...
```

My dao

```
    public List<SESSION_ENTERING> getSESSIONS() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
            createQuery("from SESSION_ENTERING order by id desc")
           .setCacheable(true)
            .list();
}
   //or even this
   public SESSION_ENTERING getSESSION() {
        return   SESSION_ENTERING)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(SESSION_ENTERING.class,256l);
}
```

Build and Deploy Succesfull,but this cacheEntries==null 
sessionFactory.getStatistics().logSummary(); is empty

```
        SecondLevelCacheStatistics cacheEntries = sessionFactory.getStatistics()
    .getSecondLevelCacheStatistics("");
    sessionFactory.getStatistics().logSummary();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have a specific question here but I can already say one thing.

Since you are using Ehcache 3.3, you should configure Ehcache through JCache instead of the `EhCacheRegionFactory` which was made for Ehcache 2.

Also, you should really use classical class names (starting with a capital letter and then lower case). It is currently a bit misleading for someone reading you.

Answer (score 0):

It was my bad.
For first I change lib ehcache-3.3.0.jar for lower ehcache-core-2.6.10.
Second I added to entity @Cacheable annotation but i am not sure  was it helpfull.